# OpenCart - how to set up one-off option price, as product quantity increases?

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

So, here's the problem:

A product costs **$10**. You then have the option to customize it (with a photo upload to be printed on it) for an additional one-off price of **$5**, no matter how many products are ordered (e.g. you can order 1 or 5 or 10000 items and the customization price will always be a flat **$5**).

Currently, when you buy, for example, twenty items and choose the customization option, OpenCart will calculate it: **(Product Price + Option Price)*Quantity = (10+5)*20 = $300** . Instead, what I aim to achieve is something like **(Product Price*Quantity) + Option Price = 10*20 + 5 = $205**

Ideally, I would like certain options to ignore the quantity (so that it will be an additional **$5** no matter how many products are ordered), while other option prices should go up with quantity (so that one product customization costs **$5**, two product customizations cost **$10**, etc.).

Surely, OpenCart must offer some way to deliver such a fundamental customer experience?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a standard feature that you will be able to do out of the box. The way I would solve this would be to create a custom `Order Total` extension and add $5 to the subtotal/total at checkout if any product has that particular option set. This does require some PHP knowledge to do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own, you could probably use the Handling Fee extension.  You may need to create a new Tax Class for that.  But as Jay said, creating your own would be ideal, and yu could certainly use the Handling Fee as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

ADD ONCE OPTION PRICE REGARDLESS QUANTITY

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=13390

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I actually purchased that extension instead - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=1888 - as it allows you to apply the one-off charge to certain items/options only, instead of applying it to all items in store.

Answer (score 0):

My commercial OpenCart extension [Setup Fees for Product Options](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14755) should do what you need. You can [see an example here](http://mavelo.com/rubber-wristbands/debossed-silicone-bracelets) by selecting the **rush production** option.